# How to convert string into integer in the Velocity template?

Tags: velocity

I have a *Velocity* template file which has the data from *XML*. I want to convert the string into integer type.

How can I do that?

Comment: you have an XSLT file that operates on an XML input document and you want to convert a field that is type xs:string into type xs:integer?

Comment: yes i have the xml input doucument which has the string value and i want to convert into integer

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Aha! Been there.

```
#set($intString = "9")
#set($Integer = 0)
$Integer.parseInt($intString)
```

Doing this uses the java underlying velocity. The $Integer variable is nothing more that a java Integer object which you can then use to access .parseInt

**Edit:** The above code is for demonstration. Of course there are ways to optimize it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I was breaking my head over why `$obj.getById("23")` works where as `#set($id = "23") $obj.getById($id))` doesn't.

Comment: works for me if I set the variable first #set($int = $Integer.parseInt($intString) )

Answer (score 10):

If you have some control over the velocity context, here's an alternative that alleviates the need to set a variable in the Velocity template.

```
Context velocityContext = new Context();
velocityContext.put(Integer.class.getSimpleName(), Integer.class);
```

This allows you to call the static methods of `java.lang.Integer` in your template using `$Integer.parseInt($value)` and doesn't rely upon the #set having been called prior to performing the type conversion in the template.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `parseInt` is that it throws an exception in case the string is not parseable.
In case you have the [NumberTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html) loaded into your context a better solution than `parseInt` is the following:

```
#set($intString = "009")
#set($Integer=$numberTool.toNumber($intString).intValue())

#if($Integer)
 ## ok
#else
 ## nok
#end
```

Sometimes the NumberTool is also loaded as `$number`.

However, a little drawback is, that the NumberTool simply parses the first number it finds and ignores the rest, so "123a" => 123.

Comment: This is the best way if you want to always parse on a best-effort basis without validating, but if you want stricter checking that fails if valid numbers are not encountered then `Integer.parseInt` may be more suitable.  Horses for courses!

Answer (score 1):

### Nice and easy:

```
#set( $stringToCast = "0" )
$number.toNumber($stringToCast)
```

`$number` is the default key name for the [NumberTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html), but it can be override by specifying a different name in the configuration (for example `$numberTool`). You have to check what name for *NumberTool* is used in your Velocity environment.

[toNumber method](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html#toNumber-java.lang.Object-) returns:

> the object as a [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html?is-external=true) or null if no conversion is possible

If you want to have explicite an `int` variable, not a `Number` object, you can use the [`intValue` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue()) on the result. So the above code will looks like this:

```
#set( $stringToCast = "0" )
$number.toNumber($stringToCast).intValue()
```

Of course, you can assign the result to another variable (for example `$intVal`).

So the full code can look like this:

```
#set( $stringToCast = "0" )
#set( $intVal = $number.toNumber($stringToCast).intValue() )
```