# Maven archetype required property number

Tags: maven, velocity, maven-archetype

I have a Maven archtype that use a `requiredProperty` that contains a number, but the velocity variable are string. So, in my template I can't test if this property is greater than a number:

```
#if( $myVar gt 5 )
```

I have tested the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156502/how-to-convert-string-into-integer-in-velocity-template) without success.

I've also tried this:

```
#set( $intVar = Integer.parseInt($myVar) )
```

That's also fail at the archetype generation.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference classes from Velociy, so `Integer.parseInt` won't work. However, since in Java any static method can be called as an instance method, and Velocity is just Java in disguise, you can call `parseInt` on any integer. So you can try this trick:

```
#if ($myVar.length().parseInt($myVar) gt 5)
```

You're getting hold of an integer starting from the one variable that you're assuming you have, `$myVar`.

Comment: another option which is a bit cleaner to use is to set Integer.class to a Velocity variable when you build up the context in Java and then reference that, i.e. in Java: context.put("intClass", Integer.class); and in Velocity: $intClass.parseInt($myVar)

Comment: Except that the Velocity part is handled by Maven, so doing that requires digging deeper in Maven.

Comment: @centic but I agree, that would be cleaner, or even better, use [`$mathtool.toInteger($myVar)`](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/MathTool.html#toInteger%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented user input validation based on a regular expression provided in the archetype descriptor :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-487

hopefully it will solve this issue for future versions of the maven archetype plugin.