# Validate Maven archetype properties

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-archetype

Is there a way to validate properties provided to a Maven archetype? If so how?

I have a custom requiredProperty in my archetype-metadata.xml file. The values must match a certain regular expression and I would like to validate that during archetype:generate.

Comment: No, unfortunately, there's not way to perform validation for properties given to an archetype. The best it can do is marking a property as required, and providing a default value.

Answer (score 5):

I have implemented this feature in maven-archetype and submitted it as a pull request :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-487

Example:

```
  <requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="pluginPackage">
      <validationRegex><![CDATA[^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)+[0-9a-z_]$]]></validationRegex>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="pluginId">
      <validationRegex><![CDATA[^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$]]></validationRegex>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="pluginName">
      <validationRegex><![CDATA[^([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*\.)*[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*$]]></validationRegex>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="pluginProvider">
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="pluginZipFileName">
      <validationRegex><![CDATA[^[^*&%\s]+$]]></validationRegex>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="pluginVersion">
      <validationRegex><![CDATA[^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$]]></validationRegex>
    </requiredProperty>
  </requiredProperties>
```

You will then get validated inputs:

```
[INFO] Using property: groupId = com.nick
Define value for property 'artifactId': abc
Define value for property 'version' 1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 
[INFO] Using property: package = com.nick
Define value for property 'pluginId' (should match expression '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$'): test-plugin525
Define value for property 'pluginName' (should match expression '^([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*\.)*[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*$'): NickTest101
Define value for property 'pluginPackage' (should match expression '^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)+[0-9a-z_]$'): com.nicholas.fun
Define value for property 'pluginProvider': Nicholas DiPiazza
Define value for property 'pluginVersion' (should match expression '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$'): 1.0
Value does not match the expression, please try again:
```

Note: It still will not regex validate the batch inputs yet. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-532

Comment: Just linking to your own library is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code using the library to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)

Comment: This is not self promotion... I'm not linking to my own library, I'm linking to an open source contribution I made to the original library used by the author of the question. Which is an exact implementation of the feature he requested, requiring no further explanation.

Comment: I agree just adding a link is lame (though definitely not self-promotion, omg lol). I added a working example plus the output showing it working.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at this now, although there is no explicit support for this in the archetype plugin or a way to set validation rules/types in the archetype-metadata.xml, as this uses velocity you can frig this and get it to do some basic validation. As the comment says - it ain't pretty but it works...

See this post [Maven archetype required property number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101681/maven-archetype-required-property-number)

UPDATE: This is now possible. See the other answer above, or https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-487