# How to cast query string to int in Integration Request Body Mapping template?

Tags: velocity

```
#set($a = 10)
#set($b = 123)
#set($c = 456)

// If query string "q1" is not available then set $q1,$q2 to default values
#if($!input.params('q1') && $input.params('q1').empty)
  #set($q1 = $b)
  #set($q2 = $c)

// If query string "q1" available but not "q2" then add some value to $q1 and set it as $q2
#elseif($!input.params('q2') && $input.params('q2').empty)
  #set($q1 = $input.params('q1'))
  #set($q2 = $a + $q1 )

// If both query strings available then set them
#else
  #set($q1 = $input.params('q1'))
  #set($q2 = $input.params('q2'))
#end
```

I'm triying the above code in Integration request body mapping template. In second case where only **q1** is specified as some number (let's say 10) then **$q2** should be 22( 12 + 10) but it's becoming as 1210, I assume this is because those $q1 and $q2 are strings and they are getting combined.

So I tried to cast them using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2156593/2007486) answer, but I'm getting internal server error.

How can I cast string to int and them as integers?

Answer (score 0):

The solution given in the other question works for me. Try this (just the second part of if-else):

```
#set($a = 10)
#set($q1 = $input.params('q1'))
#set($Integer = 0)
#set($q2 = $Integer.parseInt($q1) + $a)
{
  "params" : {
    "a" : "$a",
    "q1" : "$q1",
    "q2" : "$q2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this.

Comment: No it's still 500 error with log message `Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request`

Comment: Did you miss to add the parameter 'q1' in the method request?