# If Else Construct with Comparison not Working In Velocity Template

Tags: velocity, velocity-template-language

I have below **velocity template** construct

```
#if($no_of_entries > 1)          
    <strong>Its True !!</strong>
#else
    <strong>Its False !!</strong>
#end
```

Even when  `$no_of_entries` is **greater than 1** , **say 10 ,** it prints **Its False** !!

That means `$no_of_entries > 1` is not working

Why the `$no_of_entries > 1` condition returning false ?

I tried printing the value for `$no_of_entries` and it prints correct value **which is > 1**

**EDIT  :**

I also tried using below code

```
#if( Integer.parseInt($no_of_entries) > 1)    

    <strong>Its True !!</strong>
#else

     <strong>Its False !!</strong>
#end
```

But it is not working and throwing below exception -

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "Integer" at file.vm
Was expecting one of:
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    "(" ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "{" ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...
```

Comment: What's `no_of_entries` object? List/ Integer/...

Comment: Oh. Its string . That's why it seems not working . Let me pass int and check

Comment: Which version of Velocity are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a number it should work, if it's a String, [parse it as Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156502/how-to-convert-string-into-integer-in-the-velocity-template/17602578#17602578):

```
#set($Integer = 0)
#if($Integer.parseInt($no_of_entries) > 1)
```

Or if it's a list use `size()` method

```
#if($no_of_entries.size() > 1)
```

Comment: Yes.I tried same way . It is giving exception : Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "Integer"

Comment: @Atul see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156502/how-to-convert-string-into-integer-in-the-velocity-template/17602578#17602578